# C# opc-client .net api

Tags: c#, opc

I'm writing opc client, using .NET API from opc foundation.

In samples I only see, where item's names are hardcoded like:

```
items[0] = new Opc.Da.Item();
items[0].ItemName = "blahblahblah";
```

What I want, is not to write names of all items by my hands.
I want to load all items from server, into tree for example.
How can I do it?

Comment: Looks to me like you are looking at the wrong samples.  That would be server code, far more common in OPC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can browse the server with the following construct:

```
using Opc.Da;
using Server=Opc.Da.Server;
using Factory=OpcCom.Factory;

string urlstring = string.Format("opcda://{0}/{1}/{{{2}}}", _hostName, _serverName, serverid);
Server s = new Server(new Factory(), new URL(urlstring));
s.Connect();
ItemIdentifier itemId = null;
BrowsePosition position;
BrowseFilters filters = new BrowseFilters() {BrowseFilter = browseFilter.item};
BrowseElement[] elements = s.Browse(itemId, filters, out position);
```

The tags are in elements[i].Name.

Comment: yes. i used same code. but. i have folders on server... and your code doesnt show them

Comment: Change {BrowseFilter = browseFilter.item}; to {BrowseFilter = browseFilter.all};

Answer (score 2):

You load the items from XML file. You create XML file once with as many items as you want, then you only edit it when needed. To parse it, you can use MSXML DOM, for example. There is a parser in VB.NET [Parsing XML file in VB.NET using DOM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/ParsingXMLFileInVBNET.aspx). But you can can search for implementation in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not familiar with your opc client library, but you should be able to browse the servers items. This is a common feature used by many standalone OPC-Clients.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function Browse(ByRef node As TreeNode, Optional id As Opc.ItemIdentifier = Nothing) As Integer
    Try
        Dim clone As Opc.Da.Server = your_connected_server
        Dim filters As New Opc.Da.BrowseFilters
        filters.BrowseFilter = Opc.Da.browseFilter.all
        Dim pos As Opc.Da.BrowsePosition = Nothing
        Dim elements() As Opc.Da.BrowseElement = clone.Browse(id, filters, pos)
        If (elements IsNot Nothing) Then
            For Each element As Opc.Da.BrowseElement In elements
                Console.WriteLine(element.ItemName)
                AddBrowseElement(node, element)
                If (element.HasChildren = True) Then
                    id = New Opc.ItemIdentifier(element.ItemPath, element.ItemName)
                    Browse(node.Nodes.Item(node.Nodes.Count - 1), id)
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Return 0
    Catch ex As Exception
        RaiseEvent OnException(GetCurrentMethod, ex)
        Return -1
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub AddBrowseElement(ByRef parent As TreeNode, element As Opc.Da.BrowseElement)
    Dim node As TreeNode = New TreeNode(element.Name)
    node.Text = element.Name
    node.Tag = element

    ' add properties
    If (element.Properties IsNot Nothing) Then
        For Each [property] As Opc.Da.ItemProperty In element.Properties
            AddItemProperty(node, [property])
        Next
    End If
    ' add to parent.
    parent.Nodes.Add(node)
End Sub
```

Comment: You call the Browse function with a TreeNode object:
Dim node As New TreeNode("Root")
Browse(node)

The Browse function then call's it self recursivly.
When done you have all the servers tags in the node control.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML or NLOG or log4NET file to load the tag items.

Use opcdaauto.dll.Its a free dll for OPC Foundation Members